# The top bar is a little too full for moderators on mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, top-bar

Alternate title: why can't I hold all these icons??

The top bar has a bit too much stuff in it on my phone when there's flags:

[image: a screenshot of the top bar on my phone, with search, some flag notifications, my avatar, inbox, etc]

You might spot the issue already: the site switcher icon has been pushed halfway off the screen by the sheer quantity of stuff in the top bar.

[image: the site switcher opened up, the icon is only halfway visible on the screen]

I'm on a Google Pixel 3. Apparently my browser screen is about 393px wide.

Comment: It scrolls. But the scroll indicator is easy to miss.

Comment: @Catija So it does! I may have tried to scroll via the left half once upon a time (which doesn't scroll) and concluded the entire thing must not scroll.

Comment:  Maybe turn this into a “scroll indicator in top bar is easy to miss” question? I think it could be more obvious when it scrolls and what part scrolls.

Comment: It shouldn't scroll, no other site's top menu scroll horizontally. There's an easy solution to this too: consolidate down to one hamburger menu.

Comment: I personally think that is a bad solution. They’re not just links, they’re actual content. I would much rather have scrolling than a crazy hamburger that took several clicks to get to anything and causes me to lose the indicators for new notifications or rep changes. Having the scroll also means that SE isn’t deciding what’s less important to me.

Comment: @Rob Not a userscript problem. This is Chrome browser on Android, so I can't install userscripts to begin with.

Comment: Doppelgreener, [apparently you can](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) but no matter.

Comment: @Rob The reviews on [the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.biniok.tampermonkey&hl=en) it is pointing to don't look super encouraging. Also it was last updated 7 years ago...

Comment: @Rubiksmoose tampermonkey is one of the standard userscript extensions, it's fine. I'm using it on my desktop. I can't install it on my phone though still: I just get an "install on desktop" button which installs it on any connected desktop Chrome browsers I'm signed into, but not my phone.